# React-Redux state lost after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm really new to React and Redux, I've been following Stephen Grider's Advanced React and Redux course and I'm doing the client side of the authentication. I already have a token saved on my local storage and everything seemed to work fine until I refreshed the page. When I sign in/sign up the navigation changes to display the log out button but then if I manually refresh the page the navigation changes back to display the sign in/sign up buttons.

I'm really new to this and have no idea what should I include as code snippets. I'll leave the reducer and the actions/index.js. Also [this](https://github.com/OmarAguinaga/hoopit-token/tree/client-side) is a lik for my git repository.

actions/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
import { AUTH_USER, UNAUTH_USER, AUTH_ERROR } from './types';

const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';

export function signinUser({ username, password }) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    // Submit username/password to the server
    axios
      .post(`${API_URL}/signin`, { username, password })
      .then(response => {
        // If request is good...
        // - Update state o indicate user is authenticated
        dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
        // - Save the JWT token to local storage
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
        // - Redirect to the route '/feature'
        browserHistory.push('/feature');
      })
      .catch(() => {
        // If request is bad...
        // -Show an error to the user
        dispatch(authError('Bad login info'));
      });
  };
}

export function signupUser({ username, email, password }) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios
      .post(`${API_URL}/signup`, { username, email, password })
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
        browserHistory.push('/feature');
      })
      .catch(response => {
        // TODO
        console.log(response);
        dispatch(authError('There was an error'));
      });
  };
}

export function authError(error) {
  return {
    type: AUTH_ERROR,
    payload: error
  };
}

export function signoutUser() {
  localStorage.removeItem('token');
  return { type: UNAUTH_USER };
}
```

reducer/auth_reducer.js

```
import { AUTH_USER, UNAUTH_USER, AUTH_ERROR } from '../actions/types';
export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AUTH_USER:
      return { ...state, error: '', authenticated: true };
    case UNAUTH_USER:
      return { ...state, authenticated: false };
    case AUTH_ERROR:
      return { ...state, error: action.payload };
  }

  return state;
}
```

Thanks in advance, if you need any extra code snippet just please let me know.

Comment: Are you trying to do `localStorage.getItem('token')` and logging in the user as soon as the app mounts? Because it's not going to happen by itself.

Comment: To be clear: all `state` is lost when you refresh the page; anything you want saved has to be manually saved and restored.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I persist redux state tree on refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195590/how-can-i-persist-redux-state-tree-on-refresh)

Answer (score 18):

> do not reinvent the wheel

To store redux state even after page refresh you can use

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

It is easy to implement and robust.

Answer (score 15):

In your reducer file reducer/auth_reducer.js you can define the initial state of the reducer.

```
const initialState = { 
user: localStorage.getItem('user'), foo:'bar',
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    ...
```

in your initialState you can load stuff from localstorage or from a cookie (cookie is preferred for auth stuff).

initialState can also be setup in your createStore. It's up to you. Where you need the initial state. I use async for my routes so I can't use createStore to hold all my initial state since some routes maybe never be loaded.

```
const initialState = {
  user: localStorage.getItem('user'),
};

const store = createStore(mainReducer, initialState);
```

There is a library you can use called redux-persist. This will give you more control of what state you want to keep. (https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

Answer (score 9):

To retain Redux state through page refreshes, you need to persist the app state by storing it in `localStorage` and retrieve it on page load. Try to dispatch an action in the `componentDidMount` of your `App` component, which retrieves the data from the `localStorage`

Answer (score 8):

You need to persist app state in localStorage. [Here](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage) is a tutorial made by Dan Abramov, creator of redux.

Answer (score 3):

Do something like that: i used this method for my project

```js
function saveToLocalStorage(store) {
    try {
        const serializedStore = JSON.stringify(store);
        window.localStorage.setItem('store', serializedStore);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

function loadFromLocalStorage() {
    try {
        const serializedStore = window.localStorage.getItem('store');
        if(serializedStore === null) return undefined;
        return JSON.parse(serializedStore);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        return undefined;
    }
}

const persistedState = loadFromLocalStorage();

const store = createStore(reducer, persistedState);

store.subscribe(() => saveToLocalStorage(store.getState()));
```

Answer (score 0):

we can setup store to listen the sessionStore or localStorage values, so that value will get preserve,

for example

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createBrowserHistory as createHistory } from 'history';
// import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import rootReducer from '@reducers';
import ApiClient from '@helpers/ApiClient';
import createMiddleware from '@reducers/middleware/clientMiddleware';

export const history = createHistory();

const client = new ApiClient();
const initialState = { users: JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('redux') || '{}') };
const enhancers = [];
const middleware = [
  createMiddleware(client),
  thunk,
  routerMiddleware(history)
];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const devToolsExtension = window.devToolsExtension;

  if (typeof devToolsExtension === 'function') {
    enhancers.push(devToolsExtension());
  }
}

const composedEnhancers = compose(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  ...enhancers
);

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composedEnhancers
);

const storeDataToSessionStorage = () => {
  window.sessionStorage.setItem('redux', JSON.stringify(store.getState().users));
};

store.subscribe(storeDataToSessionStorage);

export default store;
```

so that user reducer always get initial values from the session storage. (you can push to localStorage also based on your requirement)

Answer (score 0):

Please check these:-

Just you need to add one condition

```js
import { AUTH_USER, UNAUTH_USER, AUTH_ERROR } from '../actions/types';
export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AUTH_USER:
      return { ...state, error: '', authenticated: localStorage.getItem('token') ? true : false }; // just add this condition here
    case UNAUTH_USER:
      return { ...state, authenticated: localStorage.getItem('token') ? true : false }; // just add this condition here also
    case AUTH_ERROR:
      return { ...state, error: action.payload };
  }

  return state;
}
```