# Data from redux store returns undefined when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage

When I access the `FeedbackDetails` page, initially there's no issue because the state loaded from the previous page (Home page) is still available. But when I try to refresh the page, it returns an error:

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'title' of 'feedback' as it is undefined.**

Here is the code:

**Home Page**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Header from "../components/Home/Header/Header";
import Main from "../components/Home/Main/Main";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchData, updateData } from "../actions/dataActions";

const Home = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));

    if (!data) {
      dispatch(fetchData());
    }

    dispatch(updateData(data));
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <StyledContainer>
      <Header />
      <Main />
    </StyledContainer>
  );
};

........
```

**FeedbackDetails Page**

```
mport React, { useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Feedback from "../components/Home/Main/Feedback";
import Comments from "../components/FeedbackDetails/Comments";
import AddComment from "../components/FeedbackDetails/AddComment";
import { useParams, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { totalComments } from "../utils/utilityFunctions";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { updateData } from "../actions/dataActions";

const FeedbackDetails = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();
  const { id } = useParams();
  const feedbackId = id;

  useEffect(() => {
    const storagedata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
    dispatch(updateData(storagedata));

    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
    });
  }, [dispatch]);

  const data = useSelector((state) => state.data);
  const productRequests = data.productRequests;
  const feedback = productRequests.filter((item) => item.id === Number(id))[0];
  const { title, category, upvotes, description, comments } = feedback;

.............
}
```

**Data Actions**

```
export const updateData = (data) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: "UPDATE_DATA",
    payload: {
      currentUser: data.currentUser,
      productRequests: data.productRequests,
    },
  });
};
```

**Data Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
  currentUser: {},
  productRequests: [],
  category: "",
};

const dataReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_DATA":
      return {
        ...state,
        currentUser: action.payload.currentUser,
        productRequests: action.payload.productRequests,
      };

    case "FILTER_DATA":
      return {
        ...state,
        currentUser: action.payload.currentUser,
        productRequests: action.payload.productRequests,
        category: action.payload.category,
      };

    case "UPDATE_DATA":
      return {
        ...state,
        currentUser: action.payload.currentUser,
        productRequests: action.payload.productRequests,
      };

    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};
..............
```

**Reducer Index**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import dataReducer from "./dataReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  data: dataReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

I tried digging deeper into the problem and found out that `data` (from the redux store) in the `FeedbackDetails` page is `undefined` when refreshed. I thought my `useEffect` code should resolve this when I dispatch `updateData(storagedata)`, but this doesn't seem to be the case. It seems that the `dispatch` is not updating quicker than the page loads.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I believe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58462104) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by [hisam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13540349/hisam), I managed to find a workable solution based on the [suggested thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673204/react-redux-state-lost-after-refresh/58462104#58462104).

For anybody who's interested, what I did was, I changed my initialState in my dataReducer as follows:-

```
const storagedata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));

const initialState = {
  currentUser: storagedata.currentUser || {},
  productRequests: storagedata.productRequests || [],
  category: "",
};
```

It keeps the redux store hydrated, and prevent the "undefined" issue that persists. I also tried using the redux-persist library, but somehow I couldn't get it to work as intended. Hence, I opted for the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react persist, a library that will store the redux state in your local storage which can be availed even after refresh.
Using this, you can even whitelist the elements that are to be stored in the local storage and can leave others.

[React Persist Link](https://github.com/NaveenkumarMD/create-mern-app/tree/master/template/reactpersist)

The above is the link for the implementation of react persist. You can clone this and understand how to work on it.

[Redux Persist Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist)

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem when I was trying to render data from an API. When I refreshed, the API showed me that error. The solution that I found was to add `&&` as a render condition. This asks the API if we have this new information then render and if not, just keep it like that.

**Code Sample**

[image]