# How do we persist redux store without using localstorage and make full reactjs web application work offline

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga, offline-mode

I have to do full offline functionality like all redux store data should remain after page refresh/offline(network connection lost).
When user goes offline previously stored data should be used in viewing pages & for suppose i have big forms(ex: employee form with all work experience and personal details)suddenly if user loose network, data should not be lost.. should be saved somehow & after that when user is online have to store data to DB
I am using react -18.0.0 version with react-redux & redux-saga.What are the possible ways?

Answer (score 0):

lets say users are required to log in to system .once login is successfull save that
data to local storage then dispatch loginsuccess with user and token as payloads

execute  a function inside useEffect in  app.js to get back saved data from local storage and dispatch
loginsuccess with those data

inside signup function:

```
let res=await axios.post("/signin",{user});
let{user,token}= res.data;
localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
localStorage.setItem("token",token);
dispatch({ type: "loginsuccess",payload:{user,token}});
```

inside app.js :

```
useEffect(() => {
   
      dispatch(isUserLoggedIn());
        
  }, []);
```

inside isUserLoggedIn :

```
const localstorage = localStorage.getItem("user");
    if (localstorage) {
      const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
      dispatch({ type: "loginsuccess",payload:{user}});
    } else {
      dispatch({ type: "loginfailed",payload:{error:"please log in"}});
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for addressing.But using localstorage is not secure(any one can inspect view/update/delete) and storage is limited in kb

Answer (score 0):

One way can be to store your form(or state) in localstorage. Another way can be use library [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) .
I think your question is similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673204/react-redux-state-lost-after-refresh). Have a look here for more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to store your data, is to make use of the [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), it already has a great support on the latest browser versions [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=IndexedDB%20API).

There is a really good library that make use of this api but
combined with promises [idb](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb).

After picking up how you're gonna do it, you can have a watcher saga that reacts to the `online / offline` status and do the appropriated synchronization.

Also I think it's important to mention that all of the above will only take care of the data, you still need to make sure to make the `JS` and `CSS` to be available offline. on [web.dev](https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/) there is a great induction on this subject.