# Why does my useSelector return undefined when i refresh a page that initally had a value returned

Tags: redux-toolkit

I am loading data into my redux store from the RestaurantsLists components which is below

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { RestaurantType } from "../custom";
import RestaurantCard from "./RestaurantCard";
import { useAppSelector , useAppDispatch } from "../app/hooks";
import { selectAllRestaurants , fetchRestaurants } from "../features/restaurants/restaurantSlice";

const RestaurantList = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const restaurantsList: RestaurantType[] = useAppSelector((state) => selectAllRestaurants(state));
  const restaurantStatus = useAppSelector((state) => state.restaurants.loading);
  const error = useAppSelector((state) => state.restaurants.error)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (restaurantStatus === 'idle') {
      dispatch(fetchRestaurants())}
  }, [restaurantStatus, dispatch])

  let content
  if(restaurantStatus === 'pending'){
    content = <div>Loading</div> /*chanage this into a loading component*/
  }else if(restaurantStatus === 'completed'){
    content = restaurantsList.map((restaurant: RestaurantType) => (
      <article key={restaurant._id} className="mx-2 my-10 shadow-lg sm:flex">
        <RestaurantCard
          name={restaurant.name}
          location={restaurant.location}
          path={restaurant.path}
          _id={restaurant._id}
          active={restaurant.active}
        />
      </article>
    ));
  }else if(restaurantStatus === 'failed'){
    content = <div>{error}</div> // change to an error component
  }

  return (
    <div
      className="
      max-w-4xl
      mx-auto
    "
    >
      {content}
    </div>
  );
};

export default RestaurantList;
```

Here is my slice

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import type { RootState } from "../../app/store";
import { RestaurantType } from "../../custom";

export interface RestaurantState {
  restaurants: RestaurantType[];
  loading: "idle" | "pending" | "completed" | "failed";
  error:| string| undefined /*undefined was initially null, change it to resolve error in the extra reduces rejected case*/;
}

type ActiveData = {
  _id: string;
  active: boolean;
};

const BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/restaurants/";

export const toggleActive = createAsyncThunk(
  "restaurants/toggleActivity",
  async (data: ActiveData) => {
    const { _id, active } = data;
    const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}activity/${_id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ active }),
    });

    const result =  await response.json()
    return result.response


  }
);

export const fetchRestaurants = createAsyncThunk(
  "restaurants/fetchRestaurants",
  async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}`);
    const result = await response.json();
    return result.response;
  }
);

export const addRestaurant = createAsyncThunk(
  "restaurants/addRestaurant",
  async (restaurant: RestaurantType) => {
    console.log(restaurant)
    const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(restaurant),
    });
    const result = await response.json();
    return result;
  }
);

export const deleteRestaurant = createAsyncThunk(
  "restaurants/deleteRetsuarant",
  async (id: string) => {
    const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    const result = await response.json();
    return result.response;
  }
);

const initialState: RestaurantState = {
  restaurants: [],
  loading: "idle",
  error: undefined,
};

export const restaurantSlice = createSlice({
  name: "restaurant",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateRestaurant: (state, action: PayloadAction<RestaurantType>) => {
      state.restaurants = [
        action.payload,
        ...state.restaurants.filter(
          (restaurant) => restaurant.id !== action.payload.id
        ),
      ];
    },
  },

  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchRestaurants.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = "pending";
      })
      .addCase(fetchRestaurants.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = "completed";
        state.restaurants = [...action.payload];
      })
      .addCase(fetchRestaurants.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = "failed";
        state.error = action.error.message;
      })
      .addCase(addRestaurant.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.restaurants = [...state.restaurants, action.payload];
      })
      .addCase(deleteRestaurant.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        const id = action.payload._id;
        state.restaurants = state.restaurants.filter(
          (restaurant) => restaurant._id !== id
        );
      });
  },
});

export const { updateRestaurant } = restaurantSlice.actions;
export const selectAllRestaurants = (state: RootState) => state.restaurants.restaurants;
export const selectRestaurantById = (state: RootState, id: string) =>  state.restaurants.restaurants.find((restaurant) => restaurant._id === id)
export default restaurantSlice.reducer;
```

When i click on one of the Restaurants cards, it naviagtes to a page that shows the card. When i refresh this page, I can no longer the card again.

```
import { useState, ChangeEvent, FormEvent, MouseEvent } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "../app/hooks";
import { selectRestaurantById } from "../features/restaurants/restaurantSlice";
import { updateRestaurant } from "../features/restaurants/restaurantSlice";
import ImagePreview from "./partials/ImagePreview";
import store from "../app/store";

const UpdateRestaurant = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  console.log(store.getState().restaurants.restaurants)
  const selectedRestaurant = useAppSelector((state) => selectRestaurantById(state, id as string));
  console.log(id, selectedRestaurant)
  if (!selectedRestaurant) return <div>Item not found</div>;
  const { _id, name, location, contact, path, active } = selectedRestaurant;
  const [contactEdit, setContact] = useState<string>(contact);
  const [file, setFile] = useState<undefined | File>();
  const [locationEdit, setLocation] = useState<string>(location);
  const [nameEdit, setName] = useState<string>(name);
  const [localPath, setLocalPath] = useState<string>("");

  const handleImageUpload = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setFile(event.target.files?.[0]); // displays the live uploaded image
  };

  const clearFields = () => {
    setName("");
    setLocation("");
    setContact("");
    setLocalPath("");
  };

  const handleFormSubmit = (
    event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement> | MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>
  ) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newRestaurant = {
      id,
      name: nameEdit,
      location: locationEdit,
      status,
      path,
      contact: contactEdit,
    };
    dispatch(updateRestaurant(newRestaurant));
    clearFields();
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex h-full items-center">
      <form
        className="bg-black rounded-lg max-w-96 mx-auto my-10 h-max md:flex md:max-w-fit"
        onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
      >
        <div className="h-80 md:w-96 md:h-96">
          {(file && (
            <img
              src={URL.createObjectURL(file)}
              alt="restaurant"
              className="w-full h-full object-cover rounded-t-lg md:rounded-s-lg md:rounded-e-none"
            />
          )) || (
              <img
                src={path}
                alt="restaurant"
                className="w-full h-full object-cover rounded-t-lg md:rounded-s-lg md:rounded-e-none"
              />
            ) || <ImagePreview />}
        </div>
        <div className="space-y-5 px-6 py-4 h-80 text-gray-300 max-w-96 md:w-96">
          <h1 className="text-gray-300 text-center">Update Restaurant</h1>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="name"
              placeholder="Name"
              className="bg-black border-b-2 border-gray-400 w-full outline-none"
              value={nameEdit}
              onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
                setName(e.target.value)
              }
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="location"
              placeholder="Location"
              className="bg-black border-b-2 border-gray-400 w-full outline-none"
              value={locationEdit}
              onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
                setLocation(e.target.value)
              }
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="file"
              id="image"
              placeholder="Upload file"
              className="bg-black border-b-2 border-gray-400 w-full outline-none"
              value={localPath}
              onChange={handleImageUpload}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="contact"
              placeholder="Contact"
              className="bg-black border-b-2 border-gray-400 w-full outline-none"
              value={contactEdit}
              onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
                setContact(e.target.value)
              }
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="submit"
              value="Submit"
              className="bg-green-600 w-full h-10 rounded-full"
              // disabled={!isSubmitable}
              // style={isSubmitable ? {cursor: 'pointer'} : {cursor:'none'}}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UpdateRestaurant;
```

I tried fetching the items again using the useSelector hook hoping that it will be available in redux store but i discovered its not. Infact when i log the store.restaurants.restaurants, it is an empty array. This has shocked me too.

I thought the redux store is not refreshed on page refresh but i think i am wrong on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Redux state lost after refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673204/react-redux-state-lost-after-refresh) A Redux store exists only in memory. When you reload the page everything is remounted and has the initial values. If you would like your data to exist longer than this you'll want to persist it to longer term storage, like localStorage.