# React Redux state is lost at page refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

in my react app I have 3 components. from the 1st component by a button, I use Link to go to the 2nd component. at the 2nd I create a state (redux store), manipulate it and when manipulation is finished by submitting button I redirect to the 3rd component. at the 3rd component, I also see the state (by redux chrome tool) but here when I refresh the page (the webpack thing when a code is changed and saved), I lose the sate and get an empty Object.

this is the structure of my app.

**index.js**

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Route component={App} />
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**App.js**

```
const App = ({ location }) => (
  <Container>
    <Route location={location} path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
    <Route location={location} path="/GameInit" exact component={GameInit} />
    <Route location={location} path="/Battle" exact component={Battle} />
  </Container>
);

App.propTypes = {
  location: PropTypes.shape({
    pathname: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }).isRequired
};

export default App;
```

Here at HomePage, I have a button that links to GameInit

```
const HomePage = () => (<Button color="blue" as={Link} to="/GameInit">START GAME</Button>);
export default HomePage;
```

and the GameInit Page looks like

```
class GameInit extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const { createNewPlayer} = this.props;
    createNewPlayer();
  }
/* state manipulation till it gets valid */
 palyerIsReady()=>{ history.push("/Battle");}
 
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{ createNewPlayer})(GameInit);
```

and finally Battle component where I first see the state but lose on refresh

```
class Battle extends Component {
  render() {return (/*some stuff*/);}}

Battle.propTypes = {
  players: PropTypes.object.isRequired // eslint-disable-line
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  players: state.players
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(Battle);
```

Comment: It's natural...

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar and the solution ?

Comment: save them in localstorage

Comment: isn't Thunk here as middleware to handle this? if I want to persist everything in local storage, why should I even use redux?

Comment: you may use redux-persist otherwise

Comment: Prepare initial state and pass it via createStore(combined, { a: 'horse' }).  https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/initializingstate. From my perspective this is reason

Comment: Agree save to local store or redux-persits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I persist redux state tree on refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195590/how-can-i-persist-redux-state-tree-on-refresh)

Comment: Pass this [redux-persis](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) step by step.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can easily persist it in the localstorage. Check the example below.

```
const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
    if(serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (e) {
    return undefined;
  }
};

const saveState = (state) => {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
  } catch (e) {
    // Ignore write errors;
  }
};

const peristedState = loadState();

store.subscribe(() => {
  saveState(store.getState());
});

const store = createStore(
  persistedState,
  // Others reducers...
);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root');
);
```

---

Serialization is an expensive operation. You should use a throttle function (like the one implemented by `lodash`) to limit the number of saves.

Eg:

```
import throttle from 'lodash/throttle';

store.subscribe(throttle(() => {
  saveState(store.getState());
}, 1000));
```

Comment: This looks very convincing. so there is no need for thunk anymore?

Comment: and for seeing the state at chrome extention I should write composeWithDevTools(persistedState) ?

Comment: It doesn't change anything from your existing code. The second argument of `createStore` is simply the initialState. You still can add thunk and plug the chrome extension.

Comment: persistedState, should be placed as the enhancer? something like?
createStore( rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)), persistedState );

Comment: Aha, I got it, Thanks a lot. best solution for my case :)

Comment: Where is store.subscribe from? I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"

Comment: @Temi'Topsy'Bello I think there is an error in the code, you should write `store.subscribe(...)` after `store` declaration.

Answer (score 6):

You can use something like [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to save the redux state to `local storage` or 
to another storage system.

Answer (score 1):

My personal advice for hot reloading is using this: [React hot loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader), this prevents page reload and only switch out the altered chunk. This implies that your state never gets lost while devving.

It is pretty easy to install. You only have to add an entry and wrap your initial component in `hot` which you can get from the package.

If you need more information on how it works i suggest watching [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xsSnOQynTHs) by the creator.

Answer (score 1):

Alexender Annic Answer in correct way:

```
// persist store code
const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
    if(serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (e) {
    return undefined;
  }
};

const saveState = (state) => {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
  } catch (e) {
    // Ignore write errors;
  }
};

const persistedState = loadState();

// This persistedState is includedat the time of store creation as initial value
const store = createStore(reducers, persistedState);

// This is actually call every time when store saved
store.subscribe(() => {
  saveState(store.getState());
});


export default store;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./rootReducer";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" && module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept("./rootReducer", () => {
    const newRootReducer = require("./rootReducer").default;
    store.replaceReducer(newRootReducer);
  });
}

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

const render = () => {
  const App = require("./App").default;
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root"),
  );
};

render();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" && module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept("./App", render);
}
```

Comment: Context? What is this, what does it do, why does it do? We can't read your mind. Elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is recommending localStorage, but you can also just save to sessionStorage (which i've read is safer than localStorage) and check for the storage item on refresh.
You can set it on response success or wherever.

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem("sessionName",JSON.stringify(message.payload));
```

Then can check in your componentDidUpdate or mount.

```
  if(!isLoggedIn && !isAuthenticated && window.sessionStorage.getItem('session-name')){
            saveWhatYouWant(JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('sessionName')))
        
        }
```

I found this works much faster and you're essentially repopulating the store w/out needing to write a lot of code.

Comment: A warning for anyone going this route: SessionStorage is not shared between tabs! So make sure that's behavior that you're ok with.