# preserve State between Routing?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-state-management

**Is there a common place solution to preserving state between routes in React.js?**

*I'm not entirely sure I'm asking the right question, but to clarify here is an example:*

You search something on Google, scroll down the page and click on a link. When you hit the back button you are brought back to the same search and even the same scrolling point you left off at.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by commonplace, but a solution many developers use with React is Redux.

Redux is a state management tool that allows you to store an application state even when you refresh the page or navigate forward, then backwards.

https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact

There are multiple middlewares that have been created to make sure the state persists after refreshes - here are some examples:

[How can I persist redux state tree on refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195590/how-can-i-persist-redux-state-tree-on-refresh)