# i keep getting logged out even though i have set the authentication with protected routes in react/redux ? when i refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to make protected routes with react and redux , i have made actions on redux for initaiting auth()! 
Here's a route :

```
    <BrowserRouter baseName="/">
                        <Switch>
                            <PublicRoute  authenticated={this.props.isAuthenticated} exact path="/loginapp" component={LoginApp}  />
                            <PrivateRoute  authenticated={this.props.isAuthenticated} exact path="/dashboard" component={dashboardContainer} />
                            <PrivateRoute  authenticated={this.props.isAuthenticated} exact path="/leaderboard" component={leaderBoardContainer} />
                        </Switch>
                    </BrowserRouter>
```

Here's the custom route:

```
export const PublicRoute = ({component: Component, authenticated, ...props}) => {
    const { from } = props.location.state || { from: { pathname: "/dashboard" } };
    return (
        <Route
            {...props}
            render={(props) => authenticated === true
                ? <Redirect to={from} />
                : <Component {...props} />}
        />
    );
};


class PrivateRoute extends React.Component  {
    render() {
        const { component: Component, authenticated, ...rest }  = this.props;
        const isLoggedIn = authenticated;

        return (
            <Route
                {...rest}
                render={props => isLoggedIn 
                    ? <Component {...props} />
                    : <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/loginapp", state: {from: props.location }}} />}
            />
        );
    }
};
```

I have got 3 routes , /loginapp, /dashboard, /leaderboard , in which , i wanted the user shouldn't view /loginapp route again if the user refreshes the page and automatically should be logged in with the data saved in redux . But when i refresh the page the data gets lost and **IT STAYS IN /LOGINAPP** route AND I HAVE TO MANUALLY LOGIN.

Here is my loginapp code:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import * as actions from "../store/actions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import classes from "./LoginApp.scss";

class LoginApp extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    pushme =() => {
        console.log("==================");
        this.props.initAuth();
        this.props.authHandler();
    }


    loginFormHandler = () => (
        <div>
            <span>this is login page</span>
            <button type="button" onClick={this.pushme}>get login</button>
        </div>
    );

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={classes.LoginApp}>
                {this.loginFormHandler()}
            </div>
        );

    }
}

LoginApp.propTypes = {
    initAuth: PropTypes.func,
    authHandler: PropTypes.func,
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
    location: PropTypes.object
};


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isAuthenticated:  state.auth.isAuthenticated
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        initAuth: () => dispatch(actions.initAuth()),
        authHandler: () => dispatch(actions.authSignIn())
    };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(LoginApp);
```

here is the action creator / and the reducer is already created by me:

```
export const authSignIn = () => async (dispatch) => {
    const success = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("iphonexs@apple.com", "12345678").catch((error) =>  console.error(error));
    success.user.uid !== undefined ?
        dispatch(authSuccess(success.user.displayName)) : 
        dispatch(authFailed("INVALID : FAILED TO LOG IN "));

};
```

Please have a look. i have been stuck .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i wanted the user shouldn't view /loginapp route again if the user refreshes the page and automatically should be logged in with the data saved in redux . But when i refresh the page the data gets lost and IT STAYS IN /LOGINAPP route AND I HAVE TO MANUALLY LOGIN.

That's the expected behavior. Redux is not a persistent data store, when you reload the page everything will be gone. To persist authentication status across reloads, you would need to save the state in [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) with regard to your needs.

Also the following question may be helpful for you.

- [How can I persist redux state tree on refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195590/how-can-i-persist-redux-state-tree-on-refresh)