# React Redux: How do make my store data persist on refreshing and going to other pages?

Tags: redux

I'm trying to learn how to use Redux and I was following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jULHSe41ls)

And it seems to be working as intended

[image]

Clicking on deposit and withdraw adds and decreases the amount state.

However though if you try to refresh the page, it becomes 0 again.
I thought that Redux would persist the value or am I missing something?

The code repo is from his tutorial (https://github.com/harblaith7/react-redux-crash-course)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195590/how-can-i-persist-redux-state-tree-on-refresh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I persist redux state tree on refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195590/how-can-i-persist-redux-state-tree-on-refresh)