# How to do Authentication in react using protected routes

Tags: reactjs, use-context

I am using useContext hook to sore the state to check if user loggedin or not and using protectedRoutes to protect my pages from access.
But after login, if i reload/refresh any of the proteted page, it again takes me to the login screen. WHY?

```
const [userstate, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialvalue)
return (
<>
<Mycontext.Provider value={{userstate, dispatch}}>
<Routes>
  <Route path = "login" element = {<Login/>} />
   <Route path = "/" element = {<ProtectedRoutes />}>
     <Route path="/" element={<dashboard />} />
     <Route path="welcome" element={<dashboard />} />
     <Route path="page1" element={<page1 />} />
     <Route path="page2" element={<page2 />} />
   </Route>
  <Route path = "*" element = {<Error/>} />
</Routes>
</Mycontext.Provider>
```

I am using dispatch in the login and logout buttons to set state true or false in the reducer with payload.
How can I solve this, give some solution on this.

Comment: You can't persist the data on a state on page refresh, so that's a normal behaviour. If you want to persist user's info you could use local storage/session storage/cookies and retrieve the data from there.

Comment: You can also use some redux middleware to achieve this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195590/how-can-i-persist-redux-state-tree-on-refresh

Comment: thanks, i think localStorage/cookies is the right option